# Split Date and Time from a Date to type separately

Tags: java, jsf

I'd like to do this:

```
Date meetingDateAndTime;

<h:inputText value="Date"/>
<h:inputText value="Time"/>
```

Once I got only one attribute Date, is it possible to type Date in an inputText and type Time into another and then merge them together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use two `DateFormats`, one that outputs the Date and one that outputs the Time.
[SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I thought you were trying to write two fields from one date not create one date from two fields. What about the following:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormt("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss);
String dateString = dateInputText + " " + timeInputText;
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: How do I merge them after collecting it?

Comment: You'll only need 2 Strings, one to save Date and the other to save Time, and then you do the second part of your answer with these 2 attributes and it works fine! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know that most of the methods (and constructors) in the java.util.Date class are deprecated, so I suggest you to use the java.util.GregorianCalendar instead.

Try this:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.meetingDate}">
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
</h:inputText>
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.meetingTime}">
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="hh:mm:ss" />
</h:inputText>
```

Here's the backing bean:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class MyBean {
    private GregorianCalendar fullMeetingDateTimeInfo = new GregorianCalendar();
    private Date meetingDate;
    private Date meetingTime;

    public Date getMeetingDate() { return meetingDate; }

    public Date getMeetingTime() { return meetingTime; }

    public Date setMeetingDate(Date meetingDate) { 
       this.meetingDate = meetingDate;
       fullMeetingDateTimeInfo.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(meetingDate)));
       fullMeetingDateTimeInfo.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(meetingDate)));
       fullMeetingDateTimeInfo.set(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(meetingDate)));
    }

    public Date setMeetingTime(Date meetingTime) { 
       this.meetingTime = meetingTime;
       fullMeetingDateTimeInfo.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("H").format(meetingTime)));
       fullMeetingDateTimeInfo.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(meetingTime)));
       fullMeetingDateTimeInfo.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("ss").format(meetingTime)));
    }

    public GregorianCalendar getFullMeetingDateTimeInfo() {
        return fullMeetingDateTimeInfo;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm merging the date info from the one Date object with the time info from the other Date object. The merged data is stored in the **fullMeetingDateTimeInfo** property.
So, in further you have to work with the **fullMeetingDateTimeInfo** property if you'd like to have the complete meeting-time info merged in one object.

Good luck !

Konstantin

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<h:inputText value="dateobject">
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
<h:inputText value="dateobject">
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="hh:MM:ss" />
</h:inputText>
```

doh, I misunderstood the question :o)

Comment: Please clarify whether this answer is one you are happy with. Saying you misunderstood the question muddles your response. You could delete that comment or edit/delete your answer.