# Pass date and time to textviews when button is pressed - Android

Tags: android, date, time

So I have a button that when I click the current date and time will be shown to two TextView, one is for the date and the other one is for the time. My problem is I don't know how to separate the date and time because it shows the complete current date. Can someone help me I'm new to android development. Here is my code.

```
public class Mydate extends Activity {
    Button b1;
    TextView tv, tv2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl2);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new click());
    }

    class click implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Date d = new Date();

            tv.setText(d.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: d.getMonth(), d.getMinutes(), d.getHours(), ... Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) for the documentation.

Comment: Check this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821381/split-date-and-time-from-a-date-to-type-separately

Comment: @Takendarkk can you help me how to add this to my code. Im a beginner. :(

Comment: @Libin Can you help me how to put it in my code?

Comment: This is really a simple matter of looking at the documentation for a list of methods. You should practice reading the documentation as it will solve a lot of your smaller problems like this one. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) is the link for the newer `Calendar` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest you start using the `Calendar` class instead of `Date` because many methods of Date are deprecated. To use what you already have, after you create your `Date` object like this

```
Date d = new Date();
```

you can access the individual parts of that object by using method calls other than just toString(). You should replace this line

```
tv.setText(d.toString());
```

with code along the lines of

```
// To set the text as the date like MM/DD/YEAR
tv.setText(d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getDay() + "/" + d.getYear());

// To set the text as the time
tv.setText(d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes());
```

You can use the links in my comments to read about all the methods you can use with a Date/Calendar object.

Comment: why it is deprecated? and the month shows only the first digit?

Comment: It just means it is older. Calendar is newer and can probably do everything that Date can, and then some more. I haven't tested these so I can't say 100% what will be returned. For example, if the month is February I don't know if it returns 2 or 02.

Comment: Can I ask how to do it in my code? and change it to calendar?

Comment: Click the link in my earlier comment to look at the documentation for the `Calendar` class. It will describe exactly how to use it and provide you with the entire list of available methods. If you read the documentation for the Date class, if a method is deprecated it will provide a link to the preferred version in the Calendar class.

Comment: Okay I get it and its working now, only the hour and the month is decreased by 1. how?

Comment: Maybe the months are 0 index based meaning January = 0, February = 1, etc. You can just add 1 to whatever the method returns like `d.getHours() + 1`.

Comment: Okay thanks. but there's one more thing, the AM_PM returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SimpleDateFormat class for formatting date in your desired format.

Just check this link where you get idea for your example.

For example:

```
String dateStr = "04/05/2010"; 

SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr); 
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); 

String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
```

Update:

Detailed example is here, I would suggest you to go through this example and understand the concept of SimpleDateFormat class.

Final Solution:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```